# Easiest way to set all files with Build action 'None' to 'Copy alway to output directory'

Tags: visual-studio

I had to add many files (1000+) to a Visual studio project. Newly added files that do not originally belong to the project type are added with build action 'None' and Output mode set to 'Don't copy'

I would like to change the output action to 'copy always'. If you Guys don't come up with a smarter idea I would build a console app und do same Xml transformation from

```
<None Include="some\file.json" />
```

to

```
<None Include="some\file.json">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</None>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution in a blog post by [Shaun Xu](http://geekswithblogs.net/shaunxu/archive/2012/09/20/node.js-adventure---host-node.js-on-windows-azure-worker-role.aspx). Feed the proj file via command line arg and all Content/None Items are set to Copy always.

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (args.Length < 1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Usage: copyallalways [project file]");
        return;
    }

    var proj = args[0];
    File.Copy(proj, string.Format("{0}.bak", proj));

    var xml = new XmlDocument();
    xml.Load(proj);
    var nsManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(xml.NameTable);
    nsManager.AddNamespace("pf", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003");

    // add the output setting to copy always
    var contentNodes = xml.SelectNodes("//pf:Project/pf:ItemGroup/pf:Content", nsManager);
    UpdateNodes(contentNodes, xml, nsManager);
    var noneNodes = xml.SelectNodes("//pf:Project/pf:ItemGroup/pf:None", nsManager);
    UpdateNodes(noneNodes, xml, nsManager);
    xml.Save(proj);

    // remove the namespace attributes
    var content = xml.InnerXml.Replace("<CopyToOutputDirectory xmlns=\"\">", "<CopyToOutputDirectory>");
    xml.LoadXml(content);
    xml.Save(proj);
}

static void UpdateNodes(XmlNodeList nodes, XmlDocument xml, XmlNamespaceManager nsManager)
{
    foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
    {
        var copyToOutputDirectoryNode = node.SelectSingleNode("pf:CopyToOutputDirectory", nsManager);
        if (copyToOutputDirectoryNode == null)
        {
            var n = xml.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "CopyToOutputDirectory", null);
            n.InnerText = "Always";
            node.AppendChild(n);
        }
        else
        {
            if (string.Compare(copyToOutputDirectoryNode.InnerText, "Always", true) != 0)
            {
                copyToOutputDirectoryNode.InnerText = "Always";
            }
        }
    }
}
```